std_msgs/msg/MultiArrayLayout.hpp not found when migrating ROS 1 package to ROS2
I am a beginner at ROS and trying to migrate a ROS 1 package to ROS 2. I followed most steps from links 1 and 2. I also commented some lines in package.xml, CMakeLists.txt and my .cpp file which I assume is not needed for now.
When I run colcon build, it comes out with the error:
--- stderr: ros_braccio_opencv_obj_detect_grab                             
/home/sany/ros2_braccio/src/braccio_opencv_ws/src/ros_braccio_opencv_obj_detect_grab/parse_and_publish/parse_and_publish.cpp:8:10: fatal error: std_msgs/msg/MultiArrayLayout.hpp: No such file or directory
    8 | #include "std_msgs/msg/MultiArrayLayout.hpp"
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
gmake[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/parse_and_publish.dir/build.make:76: CMakeFiles/parse_and_publish.dir/parse_and_publish/parse_and_publish.cpp.o] Error 1
gmake[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:137: CMakeFiles/parse_and_publish.dir/all] Error 2
gmake: *** [Makefile:146: all] Error 2
---
Failed   <<< ros_braccio_opencv_obj_detect_grab [3.08s, exited with code 2]

Summary: 0 packages finished [3.54s]
  1 package failed: ros_braccio_opencv_obj_detect_grab
  1 package had stderr output: ros_braccio_opencv_obj_detect_grab

This is the package.xml file. (Commented was mostly the ROS 1 code)
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--package-->
<package format="2">
  <name>ros_braccio_opencv_obj_detect_grab</name>
  <version>0.0.0</version>
  <description>The ros_braccio_opencv_obj_detect_grab package</description>

  <maintainer email="will.stedden@gmail.com">stedn</maintainer>
  <license>BSD</license>

  <!--buildtool_depend>catkin</buildtool_depend!-->
  <buildtool_depend>ament_cmake</buildtool_depend>

  <!--run_depend>controller_manager</run_depend>
  <run_depend>diff_drive_controller</run_depend>
  <run_depend>gazebo_ros</run_depend>
  <run_depend>gazebo_ros_control</run_depend>
  <run_depend>joint_state_publisher</run_depend>
  <run_depend>position_controllers</run_depend>
  <run_depend>robot_state_publisher</run_depend>
  <run_depend>rqt_robot_steering</run_depend>
  <run_depend>rviz</run_depend>
  <run_depend>xacro</run_depend!-->

  <depend>rclcpp</depend>
  <depend>std_msgs</depend>

  <depend>controller_manager</depend>
  <depend>diff_drive_controller</depend>
  <!--depend>gazebo_ros</depend!-->
  <!--depend>gazebo_ros_control</depend!-->
  <depend>joint_state_publisher</depend>
  <depend>position_controllers</depend>
  <depend>robot_state_publisher</depend>
  <depend>rqt_robot_steering</depend>
  <!--depend>rviz</depend!-->
  <depend>xacro</depend>

  <export>
    <build_type>ament_cmake</build_type>
  </export>
</package>

This is the CMakeLists.txt (where commented is ROS1 code as previously)
#cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)

project(ros_braccio_opencv_obj_detect_grab)

if(NOT CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD)
  set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
endif()
if(CMAKE_COMPILER_IS_GNUCXX OR CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID MATCHES "Clang")
  add_compile_options(-Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic)
endif()

 ## Find catkin and any catkin packages
#find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS roscpp sensor_msgs)
find_package(ament_cmake REQUIRED)
find_package(rclcpp REQUIRED)
find_package(sensor_msgs REQUIRED)
find_package(std_msgs REQUIRED)


## Declare a catkin package
#catkin_package()

#include_directories(include ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS})
include_directories(include)

add_executable(parse_and_publish parse_and_publish/parse_and_publish.cpp)

#target_link_libraries(parse_and_publish ${catkin_LIBRARIES})
ament_target_dependencies(parse_and_publish
  rclcpp
  std_msgs
  sensor_msgs)

#install(DIRECTORY launch urdf stl rviz parse_and_publish
#  DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_SHARE_DESTINATION})
install(DIRECTORY launch urdf stl rviz parse_and_publish
  DESTINATION lib/${PROJECT_NAME})
install(DIRECTORY include/
  DESTINATION include)
ament_export_include_directories(include)
ament_export_dependencies(sensor_msgs)

#add_dependencies(parse_and_publish std_msgs)
ament_target_dependencies(parse_and_publish std_msgs)

#catkin_install_python(
#  PROGRAMS scripts/braccio_xy_plane.py
#  DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_BIN_DESTINATION})

install(
  PROGRAMS scripts/braccio_xy_plane.py
  DESTINATION bin
)

ament_package()

This is the .cpp file. (again ROS1 code is commented)
//#include "ros/ros.h"
#include "rclcpp/rclcpp.hpp"

//#include "std_msgs/MultiArrayLayout.h"
//#include "std_msgs/MultiArrayDimension.h"
//#include "std_msgs/UInt8MultiArray.h"
//#include "sensor_msgs/JointState.h"
#include "std_msgs/msg/MultiArrayLayout.hpp"
#include "std_msgs/msg/MultiArrayDimension.hpp"
#include "std_msgs/msg/UInt8MultiArray.hpp"
#include "sensor_msgs/msg/JointState.hpp"

#define PI 3.1416

// Umrechnung Radian->Degree
// pi=180°
// aRadien/pi*180

/**
 * This tutorial demonstrates simple receipt of messages over the ROS system.
 */
uint _DataArray[6];

void chatterCallback(const sensor_msgs::JointState::ConstPtr& msg)
{
  int i=0;
  for(i=0; i<6; i++)
  {
    //ROS_INFO("I heard: [%d]", uint((msg->position[i])/PI*180));
    _DataArray[i]= uint((msg->position[i])/PI*180);
  }
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  /**
   * The ros::init() function needs to see argc and argv so that it can perform
   * any ROS arguments and name remapping that were provided at the command line.
   * For programmatic remappings you can use a different version of init() which takes
   * remappings directly, but for most command-line programs, passing argc and argv is
   * the easiest way to do it.  The third argument to init() is the name of the node.
   *
   * You must call one of the versions of ros::init() before using any other
   * part of the ROS system.
   */
  //ros::init(argc, argv, "parse_and_publish");
  rclcpp::init(argc, argv);

  /**
   * NodeHandle is the main access point to communications with the ROS system.
   * The first NodeHandle constructed will fully initialize this node, and the last
   * NodeHandle destructed will close down the node.
   */
  //ros::NodeHandle n;
  auto node = rclcpp::Node::make_shared("parse_and_publish");

  /**
   * The subscribe() call is how you tell ROS that you want to receive messages
   * on a given topic.  This invokes a call to the ROS
   * master node, which keeps a registry of who is publishing and who
   * is subscribing.  Messages are passed to a callback function, here
   * called chatterCallback.  subscribe() returns a Subscriber object that you
   * must hold on to until you want to unsubscribe.  When all copies of the Subscriber
   * object go out of scope, this callback will automatically be unsubscribed from
   * this topic.
   *
   * The second parameter to the subscribe() function is the size of the message
   * queue.  If messages are arriving faster than they are being processed, this
   * is the number of messages that will be buffered up before beginning to throw
   * away the oldest ones.
   */
  //ros::Subscriber sub = n.subscribe("joint_states", 6, chatterCallback); not sure if needed

  //ros::Publisher pub = n.advertise<std_msgs::UInt8MultiArray>("joint_array", 6);
  auto pub = node->create_publisher<std_msgs::msg::UInt8MultiArray>("joint_array",6);
  
  //ros::Rate loop_rate(10);
  rclcpp::Rate loop_rate(10);

  while (rclcpp::ok())
  {
    //std_msgs::UInt8MultiArray array;
    std_msgs::msg::UInt8MultiArray array;
    //Clear array
    array.data.clear();

    //for loop, pushing data in the size of the array
    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
    {
    //assign array a random number between 0 and 255.
     array.data.push_back(_DataArray[i]);
    }
    //pub.publish(array);
    pub->publish(array);

    //ros::spinOnce();
    rclcpp::spin_some(node);

    loop_rate.sleep();
  }
  /**
   * ros::spin() will enter a loop, pumping callbacks.  With this version, all
   * callbacks will be called from within this thread (the main one).  ros::spin()
   * will exit when Ctrl-C is pressed, or the node is shutdown by the master.
   */
  

  return 0;
}

I know it is a lot to digest but what should be the reason for not being able to find the MultiArrayLayout.hpp? Maybe a missing line in the package.xml or CMakeLists.txt when migrating from ROS1 to ROS2.
Thanks in advanced!

In /opt/ros/jazzy/include/std_msgs/std_msgs/msg,
there are multi_array_layout.h and multi_array_layout.hpp.
I think naming rule was changed.

For all the srv/msg naming convention in ROS 2, here is the article.
TL;DR (for your question)

If name of file is MultiArrayLayout.msg (alphanumeric characters with an upper camel case name), include name for c++ will be multi_array_layout.hpp
Name of the fields must be lowercase alphanumeric characters with underscores for separating words.

